# High availability tag seems to be irrevelevant on SO, move it on Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, serverfault

I recently posted 3 questions about high availability on Stack Overflow :

- [MySQL connection validity test in datasource : SELECT 1 or something better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982281/mysql-connection-validity-test-in-datasource-select-1-or-something-better)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945261/jboss-alfresco-cannot-write-on-slave-after-failover
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928389/jboss-dont-fail-over-mysql-slave-using-datasource

I discovered a few days later that Server Fault existed. Would it be a good idea to edit [High availability] tag to notice it ?

I read the post about differences between SO, SU and SF. Thoses differences are sometimes tiny. Should we (I say users and moderators) clearly follow this tag (and similars) and propose every time to move them ?

Should we just delete this tag, or let it live and move all posts ?

PS: the right way to move a post is flagging it, isn't it ?

Comment: Why not http://dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Wow ! Great ! I didn't ever seen this stack ! My question is larger than DBA concerns, but you tips is quite useful !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the current questions on Stack Overflow that have this tag most of them appear to be good fits for the site.

Of course the general topic of high availability will often come down to server configuration so belong more on Server Fault, explaining why there are under 200 questions on Stack Overflow, but that doesn't mean at all that valid programming questions don't exist related to how to do things in a high availability setting and I'd say the tag is highly appropriate and useful on both sites.

The current flagging and migration process seems more that adequate in this instance.